# subset a table conditional of some criteria

Tags: r

How could one subset this table, taking only the observation where there are more than two observation per country?

```
+---------+---------+------------+
| Country | firm    |  DATE      |    
+---------+---------+------------+
| A       | ABC     | 4/20/2009  |
| A       | DEF     | 12/23/2003 | 
| A       | EFG     | 6/24/2010  | 
| A       | KLM     | 6/20/2001  | 
| C       | OPQ     | 5/23/2003  | 
| C       | RST     | 6/24/2001  | 
| B       | VWS     | 7/20/2007  | 
| B       | ART     | 6/23/2003  | 
| C       | PUO     | 8/24/2002  |       
+---------+---------+------------+
```

The result should be something like :

```
+---------+---------+------------+
| Country | firm    |  DATE      |    
+---------+---------+------------+
| A       | ABC     | 4/20/2009  |
| A       | DEF     | 12/23/2003 | 
| A       | EFG     | 6/24/2010  | 
| A       | KLM     | 6/20/2001  | 
| C       | OPQ     | 5/23/2003  | 
| C       | RST     | 6/24/2001  | 
| C       | PUO     | 8/24/2002  |       
+---------+---------+------------+
```

Comment: Is this layout done in R or did you add the dividers and separators manually?  I've seen this in Python with `prettytable` but never in R.

Comment: @maloneypatr I should take no credit for this table. I just took this table from someone else post and adapted it to mine. Shamefully I don't remember the post, but I thank the author whoever it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ave` with `length` as the function. Assuming your `data.frame` is called "mydf", try:

```
ave(rep(1, nrow(mydf)), mydf$Country, FUN = length)
# [1] 4 4 4 4 3 3 2 2 3
mydf[ave(rep(1, nrow(mydf)), mydf$Country, FUN = length) > 2, ]
#   Country firm       DATE
# 1       A  ABC  4/20/2009
# 2       A  DEF 12/23/2003
# 3       A  EFG  6/24/2010
# 4       A  KLM  6/20/2001
# 5       C  OPQ  5/23/2003
# 6       C  RST  6/24/2001
# 9       C  PUO  8/24/2002
```

`ave` is a bit different from many of the other aggregation functions in R because it returns a vector the same length as the input, with values repeated according to group. This makes it ideal for something like this, where we ultimately want to subset based on a tabulated value. I've used `ave` with the first argument as `rep(1, nrow(mydf))` just to avoid having to convert to character and then to numeric when all we are doing is tabulating.

---

Even nicer, though, is to use "dplyr":

```
library(dplyr)
mydf %.%
  group_by(Country) %.%
  filter(n() > 2)
# Source: local data frame [7 x 3]
# Groups: Country
# 
#   Country firm       DATE
# 1       A  ABC  4/20/2009
# 2       A  DEF 12/23/2003
# 3       A  EFG  6/24/2010
# 4       A  KLM  6/20/2001
# 5       C  OPQ  5/23/2003
# 6       C  RST  6/24/2001
# 7       C  PUO  8/24/2002
```

The "dplyr" syntax might take getting used to, but if you take the time, you would probably find it pretty intuitive.

The three lines (each separated by `%.%`) basically say:

1. We're using the `data.frame` "mydf"...
2. We're grouping the `data.frame` by the "Country" column...
3. We're `filter`ing to select any rows where the count (calculated with the in-built `n()` function in "dplyr") is greater than 2...

---

There is, of course, also "data.table":

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(mydf)                  # Convert to a "data.table"
DT[, N := .N, by = country][N > 100, ]  # Tabulate and subset
```

Comment: hello Thanks for the answer. Both solutions are efficient indeed. They don't seem very intuitive at first sight thought. Would it be possible to add some explanation for the second one?

Comment: @DJJ, edited. Let me know if there are other questions.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `dat` is the name of your data table,

```
> dat[dat$Country %in% names(which(table(dat$Country) > 2)), ]
##   Country firm       DATE
## 1       A  ABC  4/20/2009
## 2       A  DEF 12/23/2003
## 3       A  EFG  6/24/2010
## 4       A  KLM  6/20/2001
## 5       C  OPQ  5/23/2003
## 6       C  RST  6/24/2001
## 9       C  PUO  8/24/2002
```

Comment: This is the answer I would have written. Clean and simple.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `subset`

```
> subset(dat, dat$Country %in% with(dat, levels(Country)[table(Country)>2]) )
  Country firm       DATE
1       A  ABC  4/20/2009
2       A  DEF 12/23/2003
3       A  EFG  6/24/2010
4       A  KLM  6/20/2001
5       C  OPQ  5/23/2003
6       C  RST  6/24/2001
9       C  PUO  8/24/2002
```

Another (long) way to do it

```
> do.call(rbind,sapply(split(dat, dat$Country), function(x) x[length(x$Country)>2]))
    Country firm       DATE
A.1       A  ABC  4/20/2009
A.2       A  DEF 12/23/2003
A.3       A  EFG  6/24/2010
A.4       A  KLM  6/20/2001
C.5       C  OPQ  5/23/2003
C.6       C  RST  6/24/2001
C.9       C  PUO  8/24/2002
```

Comment: I find `by` a little bit more readable: `do.call(rbind, by(mydf, mydf$Country, FUN=function(x) x[nrow(x) > 2, ]))`.